# undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I am pretty new to RoR and I have installed Devise gem successfully.  When i attempt to go t localhost:3000 I receive and error  *undefined local variable or method `` `confirmed_at' ``*   I am assuming this has to do with the Devise gem. My `schema.rb` doesnt show the

```
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
```

I have the Confirmable section non-commented in the Database, as well as added `:confirmable` in the `User.rb` file  Any help is greatly appreciated here. I'm not sure how to get the schema to match up.

Comment: Did you generate and run the migration?

Comment: i ran the migration yes, what do you mean exactly when you ask did i generate the migration?

Comment: I meant running `rails generate devise:install` as per [getting started guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started)

Comment: Yes i did, I also ran the custom

    rails g devise:views

Answer (score 4):

THANKS TO ALL THAT HELPED 
I was able to fix the problem by resetting the db using the following commands

    `rake db:migrate:reset
    rake db:reset`

and it reset it all for me.  Thanks to all!

Comment: These commands helped me aswell. Never knew there was a commadn to reset migrations.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and I solve it with this steps:

1. I Close the server
2. I open my project with `command line`, then I run these commands

```bash
    rake db:migrate:reset
    rake db:reset
```

3. I open the project in VS Code then I run

   ```bash
       rails s
   ```
4. It works